# What controls the truncation of header items in jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Below code truncates the header 'This is some header text' even though there appears to be room for the text to display. Can the text be displayed where is space available ?

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h4>This is some header text</h4>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content"  data-theme="b" id="mycontent">

        </div>

        <div class="footerDate" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">

        </div>

</div>
```

Truncated text :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the styles applied to the Header text by overridding the following class in your CSS:

```
.ui-header h<x> {

}
```

Use `text-overflow: initial;` to get rid of the ellipsis.

Play with `margin-left` and `margin-right` to make maximum use of available space on your target device.

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing in `jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css` (if you have downloaded it) or you can try overriding the style from you own style-sheet

```
.ui-header .ui-title, .ui-footer .ui-title { margin: 0.6em 5% 0.8em; }
```

you can try changing it to **5%** it would decrease margin from both sides and that would solve your problem because, it was originally like that `.ui-header .ui-title, .ui-footer .ui-title { margin: 0.6em 30% 0.8em; }`, so just try changing **`30%`** to **`5%`** or acordingly and hopefully it should work.